# Visualizing a Complex Vector Field near Poles

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, complex, visualization, vector

I've been playing around with a visualization technique for complex functions where one views the function $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ as the vector field $f: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$. These vector fields have some nice properties as a consequence of the Cauchy-Riemann equations, and usually look pretty neat. I'm surprised I haven't heard of this until recently (they're known as [Pólya plots](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolyaPlot.html)). Here's an example:

```
f[z_] := Exp[-z^2]
VectorPlot[{Re[f[x + I*y]], Im[f[x + I*y]]}, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1, 1}, 
VectorPoints -> Fine]
```

[image: Plot of the vector field f(x,y)=(Re(exp(x+iy)),Im(x+iy))]

The problem I'm having is trying to do this near the poles of functions. This is understandable, however *Mathematica* usually has no trouble plotting functions with singularities. Here's an attempt to plot $z^{-1}$:

[image: Attempt at 1/z]

I tried upping `MaxRecursion` and a couple of other things, but I figured you guys might know what to do immediately.

---

Now that the pole issue has been taken care of (thanks to everyone who contributed), here are some very intriguing plots:

Poles of $\Gamma(z)$ at -4, -3, and -2:

```
PolyaPlot[g, {-4.5, -1.5}, {-1, 1}, 50]
```

[image: Poles of $\Gamma(z)$ at -4, -3, and -2]

$\sin(z)$:

```
PolyaPlot[F, {-3 Pi/2, 3 Pi/2}, {-4, 4}, 45]
```

[image: sin(z)]

Now, here is a function that has poles over a subset of the Gaussian integers. The plot immediately reveals the symmetry of the zeros of the nontrivial polynomial

$35900-(72768-72768 i) z-128304 i z^2+(64392+64392 i) z^3-40305 z^4+(8064-8064 i) z^5+2016 i z^6-(144+144 i) z^7+9 z^8$

$\displaystyle \sum_{m=1}^{3} \sum_{n=1}^{3} \frac{1}{z-(m+in)}$:

```
PolyaPlot[G, {.7,3.3},{.7,3.3},60]
```

[image: interesting rational function]

where the function `PolyaPlot` is given by:

```
PolyaPlot[f_,ReBounds_,ImBounds_,vPoints_]:=Module[{reMin=ReBounds[[1]],reMax=ReBounds[[2]],imMin=ImBounds[[1]],imMax=ImBounds[[2]]},
    Return[VectorPlot[{Re[f[x+I*y]],Im[f[x+I*y]]},
                      {x,reMin,reMax},{y,imMin,imMax},
                      VectorPoints->vPoints,
                      VectorScale->{Automatic,Automatic,None},
                      VectorColorFunction -> (Hue[2 ArcTan[#5]/Pi]&),
                      VectorColorFunctionScaling->False]];
]
```

Comment: Isn't the Pólya vector field the **complex conjugate** of the function? This lends itself to look at things like computing the flux out of an area through a contour integral (effectively using Gauss theorem). [Code Example at MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolyaPlot.html)

Comment: Indeed, these aren't quite Pólya plots but I was trying to get a direct visualization of the function. Using the conjugate makes a lot more sense when you want to find a convenient path $\gamma(t)$ such that $\gamma '(t) = f(\gamma(t))^{*}$, so performing a contour integral reduces to $\int_{\gamma} |f(\gamma(t))|^{2}$. Turning these plots into honest Pólya plots is a matter of a negative sign.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the StreamPlots of these functions? They're even prettier!

Comment: @Rahul as are the line integral convolution plots: `LineIntegralConvolutionPlot[{Re[f[x + I*y]], 
  Im[f[x + I*y]]}, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1, 1}, RasterSize -> 300, 
 LineIntegralConvolutionScale -> 3, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][2 ArcTan[#5]/\[Pi]] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here are two suggestions for the function

```
f[z_] := 1/z;
```

First, instead of defining a *region* to omit from your plot, you should base the omission criterion on the *length* of the vectors (so that you don't have to adjust the criterion manually when switching to a function with different pole locations). That can be achieved like this:

```
With[{maximumModulus = 10},
 VectorPlot[{Re[f[x + I*y]], Im[f[x + I*y]]}, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1, 
   1}, VectorPoints -> Fine, 
  VectorScale -> {Automatic, Automatic, 
    If[#5 > maximumModulus, 0, #5] &}]
 ]
```

[image: vector plot 1]

The main thing here is that as the third element of the `VectorScale` option I provided a function that takes the 5th argument (which is the norm of the vector field) and outputs a nonzero vector scale only when the field is smaller than the cutoff value `maximumModulus`.

Another possibility is to encode the modulus *not* in the vector length at all, but in the color of the arrows:

```
VectorPlot[{Re[f[x + I*y]], Im[f[x + I*y]]}, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1, 
  1}, VectorPoints -> Fine, 
 VectorScale -> {Automatic, Automatic, None},
 VectorColorFunction -> (Hue[2 ArcTan[#5]/Pi] &), 
 VectorColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: vector color plot]

What I did here is to suppress the automatic re-scaling colors in `VectorColorFunction` and provided my own scaling that can easily deal with infinite values. It's based on the `ArcTan` function.

As a mix between these two approaches, you could also use the `ArcTan` to rescale vector length.

Comment: Thanks Jens! This takes into account all of the previous suggestions and then some and is probably the ideal way to do Pólya plots.

Comment: By the way, `Hue` as a color scheme was only a quick-and-dirty choice. If you use a more systematic gradient such as `VectorColorFunction -> ( ColorData["Rainbow"][2 ArcTan[#5]/\[Pi]] &)` then it becomes a little easier to interpret the colors. For example, this function has three zeros _and_ a pole: `f[z_] := 1/z + (z - 1)^2` - and `Hue` doesn't show that so clearly.

Comment: Good point. I've been playing around with higher values of VectorPoint and that seems to give a really intuitive picture of what's going on. I think I'll edit my post and show a couple of interesting plots such as $sin(z)$, $\Gamma(z)$, and some functions with interesting pole/zero structure.

Comment: Just for completeness, it would be good to write down the definition of your final plot function `PolyaPlot`  too...

Comment: Done. Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

You can try using `RegionFunction` :

```
g[z_] = 1/z
VectorPlot[{Re[g[x + I*y]], Im[g[x + I*y]]}, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5,1.5},
    VectorPoints -> Fine, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 >= 0.005]]
```

[image]

Another alternative is to specify explicitly the points at which you want the field :

```
points = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, Range[-1, 1, 0.5]}, {y, Range[-1, 1, 0.5]}], 1]
VectorPlot[{Re[g[x + I*y]], Im[g[x + I*y]]}, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5,1.5}, 
    VectorPoints -> points, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 >= 0.005]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is really nice, however I'm finding that it's still very fragile. Decreasing the bounds to $\left[ -1, 1\right]^{2}$ causes it break.

Comment: @JacksonWalters Added a better suggestion, please see if this helps.

Comment: your arrow at the pole (0,0) is weird, isn't it?

Comment: @F'x Yes and the documentation says that "VectorPlot omits any vectors for which the Subscript[v, i] etc. do not evaluate to real numbers". One can use RegionFunction together with VectorPoints but hopefully someone will post a better answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't know where the poles might be, just cut the function at a certain maximal value to leave a blank area around the pole:

```
g[z_] = 1/z;
h[z_] = If[Abs[g[z]] > 4, 0, g[z]];
VectorPlot[{Re[h[x + I*y]], Im[h[x + I*y]]}, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5,
   1.5}, VectorPoints -> Fine]
```

This also allows to see better the smaller vector values, without them being scaled down to much (depending on your choice of threshold).

[image]

---

Otherwise, if you know where the poles are, I'll suggest a slightly ad-hoc alternative to b.gate’s very nice solution: just make your function be zero at the poles!

```
g[z_] = 1/z;
VectorPlot[
 If[x == 0 && y == 0, {0, 0}, {Re[g[x + I*y]], 
   Im[g[x + I*y]]}], {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, 
 VectorPoints -> Fine]
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, that should do the trick. BTW, I just tried using StreamPlot and it seems to not have any of the issues that VectorPlot has while providing more or less the same information.