# Plotting complex Sine

Tags: plotting, complex

I've got another plotting problem. I want to plot `Sin[z]` where `z` is complex. So, I've tried the following:

```
Plot3D[ Sin[ x + I y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

I wanted to see how the sine function looks like on the unit circle. But... I get no output. Am I doing something wrong or is the kernel stuck?

Comment: You can plot `Re[Sin[x + I*y]]` and `Im[Sin[x + I*y]]` separately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting Complex Quantity Functions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3458/245)

Comment: See also [Visualizing a Complex Vector Field near Poles](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4244/245)

Comment: @Jens It's not a duplicate of those posts since the OP asks for plot of sine on the unit circle, although the issue is quite similar.

Comment: @Artes I see this as a special case of the linked question, but since you answered both, I'll go with your judgement here.

Comment: When reading statements here like "You can't have complex values in a plot" and "You can only treat real and imaginary parts separately", I'm tempted to refer to my method of 'really' representing the whole 4D object: you may want to take a look at [my site](http://home.scarlet.be/~pin12499/qbComplex.html) (using QB of all things:-)
. See eg the [Cosine](http://home.scarlet.be/~pin12499/animgif/Cos.gif). Now I've always been sure that programs like *Mathematica* would excel in this kind of rendering, and wondered why they don't...

Comment: @Guido, there are implementations of the "tetraview" in *Mathematica*; look up the one by Trott. Nevertheless, you really can't have *complex* values; the tetraview is generated by an appropriate *real* combination of the components of the argument and function value.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Well, you have to treat the real and imaginary parts separately. You can't really have a complex $z$ value in these plots. Here's one way to visualize complex sine:

```
Table[Plot3D[f[Sin[x + I y]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   PlotLabel -> TraditionalForm[f[Sin[z]]], 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 < 1]], {f, {Re, Im,
     Abs}}] // GraphicsRow
```

[image: complex sine]

---

One further visualization aid would be to color these functions by the argument (adapting a scheme by Roman Maeder):

```
Table[Plot3D[f[Sin[x + I y]], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[(Pi + If[z == 0, 0, Arg[Sin[x + I y]]])/(2Pi)]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotLabel -> TraditionalForm[f[Sin[z]]], 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 < 25]],
{f, {Re, Im, Abs}}] // GraphicsRow
```

[image: complex sine with argument coloring]

As Artes notes, one could have used `ParametricPlot3D[]` so that you are directly working with polar coordinates:

```
Table[ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], f[Sin[r Exp[I t]]]},
       {r, 0, 5}, {t, -Pi, Pi}, BoxRatios -> OptionValue[Plot3D, BoxRatios], 
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[(Pi + If[z == 0, 0, Arg[Sin[x + I y]]])/(2 Pi)]], 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotLabel -> TraditionalForm[f[Sin[z]]]],
{f, {Re, Im, Abs}}] // GraphicsRow
```

[image: complex sine with argument coloring, 2]

Yet another visualization possibility:

```
Table[ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], f[Sin[r Exp[I t]]]},
 {r, 0, 5}, {t, -Pi, Pi}, BoxRatios -> OptionValue[Plot3D, BoxRatios], 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[(Pi + If[z == 0, 0, Arg[Sin[x + I y]]])/(2Pi)]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, MeshFunctions -> (#4 &), 
  MeshShading -> {Automatic, None}, MeshStyle -> Transparent, 
  PlotLabel -> TraditionalForm[f[Sin[z]]], PlotRange -> All],
{f, {Re, Im, Abs}}] // GraphicsRow
```

[image: complex sine as polar ribbons]

Comment: wow, that looks great. Thank you!

Answer (score 33):

You can plot in 3 dimensions only real and/or imaginary parts of a function. One can make use of `Plot3D`, but since there was a question how the sine function looks like on the unit circle, first I demonstrate usage of `ParametricPlot3D` and later I'll show a few of many possible uses of `Plot3D`.

When we'd like to use `ParametricPlot3D`, then instead of parametrizing complex numbers like `x + I y` we would rather parametrize them like `r * Exp[ I u]`, where `r` is a radius of a circle and `u` is a polar angle. On a unit circle this reduces to `Exp[ I u]`.

```
ParametricPlot3D[
    { { Cos[u], Sin[u], Re @ Sin[Exp[I u]]},
      { Cos[u], Sin[u], Im @ Sin[Exp[I u]]}},   {u, 0, 2 Pi}, 
      PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Darker @ Green}, {Thick, Darker @ Orange}}, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image]

It would be easier to realize the structure of the graph of `Sine`, rotating  `ParametricPlot3D` around `z` axis. 
Thus we define the following functions :

```
F1[t_] := 
  Graphics3D[
    Rotate[ 
      ParametricPlot3D[ Table[{r Cos[u], r Sin[u], Re @ Sin[r Exp[I u]]}, {r, 0.1, 1, 0.1}],
                         {u, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
                            ColorFunction -> (ColorData["DeepSeaColors"][#3] &), 
                            BoxRatios -> Automatic, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False][[1]], 
           2 Pi t, {0, 0, 1}], Boxed -> False]

F2[t_] := 
  Graphics3D[
    Rotate[
      ParametricPlot3D[ Table[{r Cos[u], r Sin[u], Im @ Sin[r Exp[I*(u)]]}, {r, 0.1, 1, 0.1}],
                        {u, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
                        ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#3] &), 
                        BoxRatios -> Automatic, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False][[1]], 
            2 Pi t, {0, 0, 1}], Boxed -> False]
```

now we can animate rotation around `z`-axis :

```
Animate[
    Show[{ F1[t], F2[t], 
           ParametricPlot3D[{{Cos[v], Sin[v], -1},
                             {Cos[v], Sin[v],  0}, 
                             {Cos[v], Sin[v],  1}  }, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
                             PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Dashed, Dashed}, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
                             Axes -> False, Boxed -> False]}, 
           ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi/2, 1/2}],
          {t, 0, 1},  DefaultDuration -> 15]
```

[image]

The "deepseacolors" and "rainbow" families of curves are respectively parametric 3D - plots of real and imaginary parts of `Sine` over circles of radius `r` in the complex plane and the view point rotates around `z` - axis. The dashed circles are unit circles in planes `{x, y}` for `z` in `{-1, 0 , 1}`. Here the rotation is surplus but still advantageous for the sake of comprehensible visualization.

Now we provide static `3-D` plots of `Sine` in the complex plane.

```
GraphicsRow[{ 
    Plot3D[Re@Sin[x + I*y], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, ClippingStyle -> None], 
    Plot3D[Im@Sin[x + I*y], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, ClippingStyle -> None]}]
```

[image]

I extended the range of the plot to `{x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}` and `{y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}` since in your former case there was nothing interesting to see.

To compare with a familiar pattern of the graph of `Sine` let's restrict the range of the imaginary part of the variable, e.g.

```
GraphicsRow[{ Plot3D[ Re @ Sin[x + I*y], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -0.3 Pi, 0.3 Pi}], 
              Plot3D[ Im @ Sin[x + I*y], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -0.3 Pi, 0.3 Pi}]}]
```

[image]

or to get the equal scale for all dimensions

```
GraphicsRow[
  {Plot3D[ Re @ Sin[x + I*y], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -0.4 Pi, 0.4 Pi}, 
           BoxRatios -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "Real part"], 

   Plot3D[ Im @ Sin[x + I*y], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -0.4 Pi, 0.4 Pi}, 
           BoxRatios -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "Imaginary part"]     }, 

   PlotLabel -> "Graphs of Sine"]
```

[image]

and if you prefer the both parts of `Sine` in the complex plane in one plot :

```
Plot3D[{ Re @ Sin[x + I*y], Im @ Sin[x + I*y]},
       {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -0.4 Pi, 0.4 Pi}, 
         Mesh -> {5, 3}, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
         PlotStyle -> {{Opacity[0.35], Lighter[Green, 0.5]},
                       {Opacity[0.7],  Lighter[Blue,  0.7]} } ]
```

[image]

Comment: For a different visualization, on the Riemann sphere, see the paper "Visualizing Complex Functions with the Presentations Application," *The Mathematica Journal*, vol. 11 #2 (2009), by David J. M. Park and me. Available in CDF and PDF [here](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/volume/v11i2/). (To re-evaluate most code, and to run the dynamic examples, you'll need a copy of Park's *Presentations* application.)

Comment: @murray Thank you for pointing out interesting references. I've seen that paper.

Answer (score 4):

Since Mathematica 12.0 you can do

```
ComplexPlot[Sin[z], {z, -1 - I, 1 + I}]
```

[image: 2D complex plot]

```
ComplexPlot3D[Sin[z], {z, -1 - I, 1 + I}]
```

[image: 3D complex plot]