# The same input can obtain different results?

Tags: version-10, visualization

```
With[{f = # + 1/# &, center = 1/3 + 3 I/2, radius = 4/3},ParametricPlot[Through[{Re,       Im}[f[center + r Exp[I \[Theta]]]]], {r, 0, radius}, {\[Theta], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, PlotPoints -> 30, PlotRange -> All, MaxRecursion -> 3]]
```

in Version 9,the output is:

[image]

but in Version 10:

[image]

Is it a bug in Version 10?

the code links [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10180/plotting-a-complex-valued-function-over-a-circular-region/10184#10184).

Comment: The answer `PlotTheme -> "Classic"` has been given in [Szabolc's answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54573) to [Will Version 9 functions all work in Version 10?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54481)

Comment: I removed the [tag:bugs] tag.  This seems to be an intentional change in behavior, not a bug per se.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `PlotTheme -> "Classic"` to get V 9 output:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
With[
 {f = # + 1/# &, center = 1/3 + 3 I/2, radius = 4/3},
 ParametricPlot[Through[{Re, Im}[f[center + r Exp[I \[Theta]]]]], {r, 0, radius}, 
  {\[Theta], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, PlotPoints -> 30, 
  PlotRange -> All, MaxRecursion -> 3, PlotTheme -> "Classic"]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I am not sure why, might be a bug

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't know PlotTheme->"Classic" before this post. 

Answer (score 3):

On 10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 10, 2014) one uses:

```
With[{f = # + 1/# &, center = 1/3 + 3 I/2, radius = 4/3}, 
 ParametricPlot[
  Through[{Re, Im}[f[center + r Exp[I \[Theta]]]]], {r, 0, 
   radius}, {\[Theta], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, PlotPoints -> 55, 
  PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> Full]]
```

[image]

So, `Mesh` seems to do the trick.

Comment: `Mesh -> Automatic` allows to reproduce the output of version 9 exactly (only colors are different). It is despite the fact that by default `Options[ParametricPlot, Mesh]` returns `{Mesh -> Automatic}`.