# Plotting a Complex Valued Function

Tags: plotting

Suppose that a complex valued function `f[z]=f[x+i y]=u[x,y]+i v[x,y]`.
I want to plot3d its real part by coloring it with respect to its imaginary part.
For instance, if `m` and `M` are the smallest and greatest values of the imaginary part,
I want to color the graphic from white to black depending on the value of the
imaginary part (`m` is white, `M` is black).
I would be very glad if you can help me.

Comment: Related: [1)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3458/plotting-complex-quantity-functions), [2)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/plotting-complex-sine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't mention what functions you want to plot, here are some simple ones:

```
 v[x_, y_] := Cos[x y];
 w[x_, y_] := x y;
 Plot3D[v[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, w[x, y]]]
```

[image]

This works by choosing the `ColorFunction` to be the function `w` while the surface is `v[x,y]`, so your original complex-valued function is `f[x,y]:=v[x,y]+I w[x,y]`. As 0x4A4D points out, there are many ways to proceed: many options for `ColorFunctions` and many ways to scale these using `ColorFunctionScaling` to fine tune the appearance of the plot.

Comment: The option `ColorFunctionScaling` might be interesting for the OP...

Answer (score 2):

Yet another possibility would be to generate a density plot of the imaginary part, and use the resulting plot as a texture for the surface plot of the real part. Here's a demonstration, using $\log(z)$:

```
tex = Image[DensityPlot[Im[Log[x + I y]], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
                        AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[1 - #] &), 
                        Frame -> False, ImagePadding -> None, PlotPoints -> 45, 
                        PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> None], 
            ImageResolution -> 144];

Plot3D[Re[Log[x + I y]], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
       BoundaryStyle -> None, Lighting -> "Neutral", Mesh -> None, 
       PlotPoints -> 45, PlotStyle -> Texture[tex]]
```

[image: real part of the logarithm, colored by the imaginary part]

A nice alternative you might want to consider is `ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"GrayTones", "Reverse"}]`.