# How to plot data of complex numers

Tags: plotting

Here I have some output calculated for different values of some parameter. I want to plot these points in complex plane Re, Im and present them with ListLinePLot. How can I do that, I tried many times but nothing.

```
 out={{{K0 -> 240.09573909159692881611894479598255552782741102371 - 
 7.27635432239591082054495645853781783511810812523 I}}, {{K0 -> 
250.77439852422565327207328256124461190469681314589 - 
 31.26451978875377785592466121797901152332973976660 I}}, {{K0 -> 
253.48532269665683199525493735826312930548236644336 - 
 61.24310141078654112760472487520741696623955208560 I}}, {{K0 -> 
249.18937492291801812641504201171420536673203251135 - 
 92.38827531035059634782269285091956945472964743190 I}}, {{K0 -> 
239.10541928516975728266518199423978996138742725557 - 
 122.79360060036155629292367320357542795679835792710 I}}, {{K0 -> 
224.13192736090708008710607149524981720297486848225 - 
 151.51085317916968975506128715270875157179902970334 I}}, {{K0 -> 
204.92235646608943262261629178639026362615765825785 - 
 177.96564990038879131356133303872228920923576227697 I}}, {{K0 -> 
181.96606373954652948373275976518520695312671935521 - 
 201.74316490057697153557914766713663939352731214231 I}}, {{K0 -> 
155.64091078592068971330671363671101734468083989542 - 
 222.49208124514099845175336661804180693875258747941 I}}, {{K0 -> 
126.24620602094244454267170422247369897873670911676 - 
 239.87157975283261958986520821933642550993546879398 I}}, {{K0 -> \
-4743.5781179728666287431504651689229585059692376219 - 
 43.6738915748400328628460613215871721452209766204 I}}};
```

Comment: [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16252/plotting-complex-numbers?rq=1), [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/plotting-complex-sine?rq=1), [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3458/plotting-complex-quantity-functions?rq=1) and thousands other

Comment: `ListLinePlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ Flatten[K0 /. out]]`

Comment: @Mark Thank you

Comment: @Mark It is working