# How to plot $ \sin\theta $ in degree?

Tags: plotting, units

Please suggest how to plot $ \sin\theta $ in degree. I am trying using the given below code but it is not working (It works if used `Ticks` without `Frame -> True`).

```
Plot[{Sin[θ°]}, {θ, 0, 360}, Frame -> True, 
      PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[.009]}, 
      FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Range[0, 360, 45], 
      Automatic}}, FillingStyle -> LightBlue, Filling -> Bottom]
```

[image]

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Calculation from standard convention into degrees is trivial, just multiply an angle (in radians) by 180/Pi to get degrees. There is a question related  to plotting sinus (in radians) in complexes [Plotting complex Sine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/plotting-complex-sine)

Comment: The code works fine in Mathematica 12. In Mathematica, Degree is a constant equal to Pi/180.

Comment: All you need is a space between `θ` and `°`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to introduce units on the horizontal axis would be to define

```
ticks = Thread[{Range[0, 360, 45], 
   Quantity[Range[0, 360, 45], "°"]}];
```

And then plot with

```
Plot[{Sin[θ °]}, {θ, 0, 360}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[.009]}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {ticks, Automatic}}, 
 FillingStyle -> LightBlue, Filling -> Bottom]
```

[image]

A simple way to vary the filling color is with `Lighter` and `Darker`.  For example, `FillingStyle -> Lighter[Blue, 3/10]` makes the filling color about 30% lighter than `Blue` alone.

Another way is with `FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[7/10],Blue]`.  This also makes the filling color about 30% lighter than `Blue` alone.  `Directive` has many useful options and can be applied in many ways.

The Mathematica documentation describes many other ways to specify colors.  Another example is use `FillingStyle -> Hue[0.6, 0.2]`.  The 0.6 value makes it blue.  Lower or raise the second value to get a lighter or darker blue.

Comment: ,Thanks, It is working.Can you also suggest that how to vary opacity of filling style. Please use blue instead of LightBlue.