# Singularities using VectorPlot

Tags: plotting, vector-calculus, fluid-dynamics

I am trying to plot a vector function of a fluid flow given by

$\vec{V} = (\frac{-\cos(\theta)}{r^2},-\frac{\sin(\theta)}{r^2})$

I am trying to plot it in Mathematica using the command below, I converted to Cartesian coordinates by the way. But this does not run in Mathematica. Without the `Exclusions` option, I only get one arrow at the origin. Can you help me with this plot?

```
VectorPlot[
      {-(x/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2)), -(y/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2))}, 
      {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
      Exclusions -> {(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2) == 0} 
 ]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t).

Comment: `Exclusions` is not an option of `VectorPlot`. If you include it you only get an error message and no plot at all.

Comment: This is basically the same as [Visualizing a Complex Vector Field near Poles](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4244/245) - I'm sure you can adapt one of the answers from that question.

Answer (score 13):

You can make use of option [**VectorScale**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VectorScale.html) - see the "More Information" section, and some singular examples at the end. Setting `None` will cause all the vectors to have the same length. Or you can improvise with a custom function to make the best view of the arrows (`#5` the fifth argument is vector's norm):

```
VectorPlot[{-(x/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2)), -(y/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2))}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
VectorScale -> {Automatic, Automatic, #}] & /@ {None, Function[If[#5 > 50, None, #5^.3]]}
```

[image]

You can also use `StreamPlot`

```
StreamPlot[{-(x/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2)), -(y/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2))}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

**----- Edit: adding potential - as requested in the comments ----------**

In your case potential is easily computed as integral over corresponding coordinates. Note automating clipping in the plot range. Here is the result with `VectorPlot`:

```
Show[ContourPlot[1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  ContourStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Contours -> 20],
 VectorPlot[{-(x/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2)), -(y/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2))}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  VectorScale -> {Automatic, Automatic, 
         Function[If[#5 > 50, None, #5^.3]]}, VectorStyle -> Black]]
```

[image]

and `StreamPlot` styled a bit differently

```
Show[ContourPlot[1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  ContourStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed], ColorFunction -> "GrayTones"],
 StreamPlot[{-(x/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2)), -(y/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2))}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
     StreamStyle -> White]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! This is for a fluid flow by the way. Is there an easy way to quickly draw the streamfunction and potential function (prependicular to each other) on the same graph?

Comment: @l3win I updated the post

Answer (score 7):

`Exclusions` is not an option of `VectorPlot`. As an alternative, you could use `Boole` to exclude part of the plot:

```
VectorPlot[
    Boole[x^2 + y^2 > 0.08] {-(x/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2)), -(y/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2))}, 
    {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Combining this with the potential:

```
Show[
 DensityPlot[1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "SolarColors"],
 VectorPlot[
  Boole[x^2 + y^2 > 
     0.1] {-(x/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2)), -(y/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2))}, {x, -1, 
   1}, {y, -1, 1}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you all for the messages, you have been very helpful. I have one more question. The above was my vector field. Is there any way I can plot the potential function of my vector field? $\vec{V} = \nabla(f)$ How can I plot f?

Comment: I still get a different scalar potential. This seems to me like a single sink, I get a dipole... Thanks for all the replies though

Comment: @I3win have you calculated the gradient of 1/Sqrt[x^2+y^2]? I got the vector field in your code example. The vector plot is consistent with tat, not with te field of a dipole.