# How to visualize slope fields of differential equations without vectors?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm looking to visualize slope fields of differential equations for my differential equations course. Every example I see draws them as vectors, adding unnecessary "arrows" that, to me, are visually distracting. Is there a way to plot these slope fields without the "arrows" that get in the way?

Comment: `LineIntegralConvolutionPlot[{y, 
  x - x^3 - 0.3 y + 0.5 Cos[3.125]}, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, {y, -2.5, 2.5}, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["DeepSeaColors"], StreamPoints -> 10, 
 StreamStyle -> {"Line", Thick, White}]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visualizing a Complex Vector Field near Poles](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4244/visualizing-a-complex-vector-field-near-poles)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the options `VectorScale` and `VectorStyle` of `VectorPlot`. To create the slope field for the first order equation $y'=f(x,y)$, I usually do something like so.

```
f = Exp[-x] - y;
VectorPlot[{1, f}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
  VectorScale -> {0.03, Automatic, None},
  VectorStyle -> {Gray, Arrowheads[0]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can simply replace each occurrence of `Arrow` with `Line` like this:

```
VectorPlot[{y, -x}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}] /. Arrow -> Line
```

[image: lines]

To understand how this works, please read the documentation for `ReplaceAll` and also take a look at `FullForm[VectorPlot[...]]`. The point is to see that the plot is just a bunch of graphics directives and therefore we can modify it. Replacing `Arrow` with `Line` works because the argument is the same to both `Arrow` and `Line`.

You can also achieve it like this:

```
VectorPlot[{y, -x}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, VectorStyle -> "Segment"]
```

Look at the documentation for `VectorStyle` and especially the part under "Details" to see the full set of options. As a beginner, this is the way to go, and I should probably have used it as well. But as you get more experienced sometimes you don't want to dig in the documentation so you do something quick and dirty like what I did above. It's often useful to be able to, so I'll let the other solution remain in my answer.

*My example above was poor, it appears, since it's not a proper slope field. For that part of the question check out Mark McClure's answer.*

Comment: +1 for the `VectorStyle->"Segment"`, which I didn't know.  Not actually a slope field, however.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Thanks for pointing it out, I gave your post a +1 and added a comment about.

Comment: Well, "slightly off" would be a better description than "poor". :)