# 3D Plot for Attractive and Repuslive Field Functions

Tags: plotting

I am using Mathematica to plot the total potentials (which is the sum of an attractive potential field and a repulsive potential field) - This is related the Artificial Potential Field Method in Motion Planning, for example, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_planning#Potential_Fields).

The attractive potential is "downhill" like a bowl and the repulsive potential is "uphill" ("spike")

I have attached the output for two cases (each case has two different viewing angles).

The *first* *two figures are Case 1* and the *last two are Case 2*.

I prefer Case 2 (the last two figures) to which I have added to the Plot3D command:

```
ClippingStyle -> None
```

My problem is with the repulsive potential (the spike). There appears to some sort of "messy cylinder" (maroon in color) going through the entire spike. This is visible in View 2 of each case.

Is there anyway I can get rid of the cylinder by adding some options to Plot3D?

[image: Case 1: View 1] 
[image: Case 1: View 2]
[image: Case 2: View 1]
[image: Case 2: View 2]

***Edit*** Given below is the code for generating the plot.

```
(*Assignments*)
r = 0.5;

q = 1;

xmax = 70;
ymax = 70;

o[1, 1] = 25; o[1, 2] = 30;
A[1] = 3; B[1] = 4;

p1 = 35; p2 = 35;

(*This parameter can be changed, where g[l]>0*)
Table[g[l] = 1000, {l, 1, q}];

(*Function definitions*)
H = 1/2 ((x - p1)^2 + (y - p1)^2);

Table[EO[l] = 1/2 (((x - o[l, 1])/(A[l] + r))^2 + ((y - o[l, 1])/(B[l] + r))^2 - 1),{l, 1, q}];

(*We require the plot of the following function*)
L = H + Sum[g[l]/EO[l], {l, 1, q}];

(*The plot*)
Plot3D[L, {x, 0, xmax}, {y, 0, ymax}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[5]], ClippingStyle -> None]
```

Comment: @Kuba, Thanks. I will include the code.

Comment: @Kuba, I have added the code. I was randomly generating the position of the repulsive potential but I have kept it fixed in the code given here. The parameter g[l] is user-defined. The larger it is the greater the repulsive potential.

Comment: Use the option PlotPoints in Plot3D. For instance PlotPoints->100 gives a fairly smooth outline of the objects.

Comment: related: [4244](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4244/5478)

Comment: @ Dr. Wolfgang Hintze and @Kuba, Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior is due to your calculations, specifically the `EO[l]`-table, inducing a singularity region (i.e.: the `EO[l]`-table is 0 for the region you see in your plot).

So, the plots are "correct", which you can verify by adding the options `PlotRange->All` and `PlotPoints->250` (or even more).

You will have to fix those singularities (in this case resulting from deleting by zero) to get your desired *smooth* result.

### Proof of the singularity in the `E[l]`-table

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[EO[l],{l,1,q}]/.y->20],{x,0,40},AxesOrigin->{0,0}]
```

[image: The function constructed by the table has a zero-point]

Comment: Thank you very much. I have rewritten EO[l] as a piecewise function where I set EO[l] to 1 whenever it is 0. It solved the problem.