# Problem with 3D surface disconnections

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have a problem with a 3D surface in *Mathematica* 10.1.
The problem is that the surface comes out disconnected even if it shouldn't.
Here's a minimal toy example showing the problem:

```
Plot3D[E^-(x - Round[x])^2, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

the result is

### [image: 3D surface disconnected]

The surface profile (in 2D) is that of a continuous line (even if it is not differentiable at all points):

```
Plot[E^-(x - Round[x])^2, {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image: 2D Profile is connected]

Increasing the `PlotPoints` actually reduce the gaps' width, but doesn't eliminate them.

I have also tried the above code in *Mathematica* 9 and there's the same problem.

That effect is **very awful** in the rendering of a much more complex surface intended to reproduce a seashell (with bumps and nodules).
Is there any simple workaround to smooth out (not differentiable) surfaces?

Comment: Try a combination of `Exclusions -> None` and a larger number for `MaxRecursions`.

Comment: @Virgil Thanks. I didn't know about the `Exclusions -> None` option. It seems to work.

Comment: related Q/As: [White Lines in Contour Plot and 3D Plot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78991/125), [Why does Plot3D omit parts of the surface at kinks?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4797/125)

Comment: Luca, I hope someday you can post pictures of your simulated seashells. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the record, this can be solved by setting `Exclusions -> None` in `Plot3D`, which tells *Mathematica* not to exclude subregions of the domain that are associated with discontinuities. Generally, if you want that plot to look sharp, you will have to couple it with a largish number for `MaxRecursions`:

```
Plot3D[E^-(x - Round[x])^2, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
 Exclusions -> None,
 MaxRecursion -> 10
 PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Yet another (sneaky!) way to thwart automatic exclusion is to make the definition `f[x_?NumericQ] := E^-(x - Round[x])^2` and use that for the plots.

Comment: Instead of Exclusions-> None, there should be a command.. Inclusions-> All  :)